# MongoDb C# readonly field

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have different types of generic objects in the same document: one base object and 2 children with different properties. In the db I'm keeping only childrens, but most of all use base object which have only 2 fields and cached in memory.

But sometimes I need to get all the info of the object (children), not just base. For this I need to know the type of the children's object (from the base object).

To know the type, MongoDb use discriminators. By default it's `_t`. So I'm decided to add this default discriminator to my base class:

```
public string _t { get; private set; }
```

Now I see the type of children in `_t` property. All works fine for saved in db objects, but not for new objcets.
When I'm trying to save a new childern object in db, it's trying to pass there _t property with `value = null`. But `_t` is reserved field for discriminator, so I'm getting the error: `Duplicate element name '_t'`.

**The question:**

How can I keep `_t` property in db object model, but map this field only for read operation?

**The solution:**
The problem is actually only in new objects, so I made this:

```
[BsonIgnoreIfNull]
public string _t { get; private set; }
```

Now if `_t` is empty the mapper will ignore this property and let the mongodb driver to create a discriminator without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be [re-inventing the wheel](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#setting-the-discriminator-value) here. Either use the built-in discriminator (which will automatically serialize a `_t` field), or [write your own serializer](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#customizing-serialization).

```
[BsonDiscriminator("Base")]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(D1), ...)]
class Base { 
}
class D1 : Base {
}
```

those would be serialized *automatically* (no need to add the `_t` yourself) as

```
{ "_id" : 1, "_t" : "Base", ... }
```

and

```
{ "_id" : 1, "_t" : "D1", ... }
```

respectively.

When you add a field `_t` to your class itself, you're 'invading' the reserved space for the default serializer. Also, from an OOP standpoint, storing the class' name in the object instance doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, so it's best to steer clear of that.

Using the custom serializer, you might be able to avoid writing the discriminator value for instances of the base class, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: On, I'm not trying to manualy save object type in the db. The _t is a standard discriminator whitch saving in the db automatically and I'm not trying to change this behavior. I'm trying only to read _t. I don't want to save it in db. That's the problem.

I will look at custom serializer.
Any way thanks for help!

Comment: OK, in that case, simply read an object of type `class T { public string _t {get;set;} }`, or a `BsonDocument`. That way, the default serializer won't invoke the discriminator.

Comment: That's exactly the thing I made. That works fine for old objects that already saved in the db and have _t. But for new objects it's trying to save reserved by default discriminator field _t. That operation returns an error: Duplicate element name '_t'. And that's clear. I can't set up reserved field to save operation. So I need somehow to tell to mapper/serializer to not map/serialize _t for save operation, only for read... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'bool ShouldSerializeXYZ()' or '[IgnoreIfNull]' to prevent serialization of a field, but that might not solve the duplication of the field in the mapping.

Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686596/1728370
This solution essentially returns a 'null' discriminator value via policy for some types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).