# How to disable discriminator field in MongoDb (C# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a way to disable completely (for all classes) the discriminator ("_t") fields from being added to the bson documents?
I am referring to: [mongo-csharp-driver/polymorphism](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/#polymorphism)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say we have a `Square` and `Rectangle` that inherit from `Shape`.

```cs
public abstract class Shape
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Square : Shape
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Like you said if we run the following code.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var shapes = db.GetCollection<Shape>("shapes");

await shapes.InsertManyAsync(new Shape[]
{
    new Square{Size = 10},
    new Rectangle{Height = 5, Width = 4}
});
```

We'll get the following inserted into MongoDB

```js
db.shapes.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e2affc23dde5a501bdf0b"), "_t" : "Square", "Size" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e2affc23dde5a501bdf0c"), "_t" : "Rectangle", "Width" : 4, "Height" : 5 }
```

Initially, I thought we'd be able to set the `DiscriminatorIsRequired` flag on the `BsonClassMap` and wrap that in a convention, however, from trying this it seems to fail due to the following bit of logic in the MongoDB C# Driver.

```cs
private bool ShouldSerializeDiscriminator(Type nominalType)
{
    return (nominalType != _classMap.ClassType || _classMap.DiscriminatorIsRequired || _classMap.HasRootClass) && !_classMap.IsAnonymous;
}
```

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/9e567e23615c8bb5c7ac1489427c2d15b2124522/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/BsonClassMapSerializer.cs#L722

So because there's no way for us to tell the serializer we don't want to include a discriminator we'll have to give it a convention instead that does nothing.
If we create an `IDiscriminatorConvention` that pretty much does nothing and returns back null for the discriminator then the driver won't add this to the document.

```cs
public class NullDiscriminatorConvention : IDiscriminatorConvention
{
    public static NullDiscriminatorConvention Instance { get; }
        = new NullDiscriminatorConvention();

    public Type GetActualType(IBsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
        => nominalType;

    public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
        => null;

    public string ElementName { get; } = null;
}
```

This discriminator convention then needs to be registered against each type.

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(Square), NullDiscriminatorConvention.Instance);
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(Rectangle), NullDiscriminatorConvention.Instance);
```

Alternately if we want it on all types you could do a little bit of reflection.

```cs
var shapeTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(domainAssembly => domainAssembly.GetTypes(),
        (domainAssembly, assemblyType) => new {domainAssembly, assemblyType})
    .Where(t => @t.assemblyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Shape)))
    .Select(t => @t.assemblyType).ToArray();

foreach (var shapeType in shapeTypes)
{
    BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(shapeType, NullDiscriminatorConvention.Instance);
}
```

Now if we re-run our code.

```cs
var shapeTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(domainAssembly => domainAssembly.GetTypes(),
        (domainAssembly, assemblyType) => new {domainAssembly, assemblyType})
    .Where(t => @t.assemblyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Shape)))
    .Select(t => @t.assemblyType).ToArray();

foreach (var shapeType in shapeTypes)
{
    BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(shapeType, NullDiscriminatorConvention.Instance);
}

var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var shapes = db.GetCollection<Shape>("shapes");

await shapes.InsertManyAsync(new Shape[]
{
    new Square{Size = 10},
    new Rectangle{Height = 5, Width = 4}
});
```

we'll get our expected output.

```js
db.shapes.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e2d63ed12d7c5d3638d36"), "Size" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e2d63ed12d7c5d3638d37"), "Width" : 4, "Height" : 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using Newtonsoft bson serializer ([Newtonsoft.Json.Bson](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson)) which gives a lot of serialization options.
It isn't efficient since you need to write the bson to a stream and then read it from there with MongoDb reader but it provides lots of customization option.
Example code:

```
class BsonDocBuilder
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream _memStream = new MemoryStream();
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        private readonly JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer; 
        public BsonDocBuilder()
        {
            _jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_serializeSettings);
        }

        public BsonDocument ToBson<T>(T value)
        {
            BsonDocument bd;
            try
            {
                using (BsonDataWriter dataWriter = new BsonDataWriter(_memStream))
                {
                    dataWriter.CloseOutput = false;
                    _jsonSerializer.Serialize(dataWriter, value);
                }
                bd= BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(_memStream.ToArray());
            }
            finally
            {
                _memStream.SetLength(0);                    
            }

            return bd;
        }
    }
```